# Align a cases equation with another equation vertically on the same line

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align, amsmath

I am using the following to align the two equations. However, they are not vertically on the same level. How should I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}  
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
G(Q,N)=\sum\limits_{Q_i \in N} F(Q_i,N); \;\;
\end{split}
\begin{split}
F(n,N)= 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } n > N \\
0.5, & \text{if } n = N \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Don't set each part in a `split`. Instead, just separate them with a `\qquad` (or some other horizontal space). This ensures that the math axis is not adjusted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  G(Q,N) = \sum\limits_{Q_i \in N} F(Q_i,N); \qquad
  F(n,N) = \begin{cases}
    1,   & \text{if } n > N \\
    0.5, & \text{if } n = N \\
    0,   & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```